# Windows Phone - MediaLibrary

Tags: c#, windows-phone

It's my code.

```
MediaLibrary myMediaLibrary = new MediaLibrary();
Uri myUri = new Uri(@"Images/Jellyfish.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
System.IO.Stream photoStream = App.GetResourceStream(myUri).Stream;
byte[] buffer = new byte[photoStream.Length];
photoStream.Read(buffer, 0, Convert.ToInt32(photoStream.Length));
myMediaLibrary.SavePicture("Jellyfish.jpg", buffer);
```

On the emulator everything is saved. But on the device displays an error "An unexpected error has occurred".

Answer (score 0):

Saving your Stream directly does not work?

```
MediaLibrary myMediaLibrary = new MediaLibrary();
Uri myUri = new Uri(@"Images/Jellyfish.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
System.IO.Stream photoStream = App.GetResourceStream(myUri).Stream;
myMediaLibrary.SavePicture("Jellyfish.jpg", photoStream);
```

Alternatively you can use `WriteableBitmap` and save this into `Stream` and then save it with `MediaLibray`.

```
wr.SaveJpeg(FileStream, wr.PixelWidth, wr.PixelHeight, 0, 85);
```